# Entropy for $N$ number of particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

> If there are $N$ number of non-interacting and distinguishable particles which have either Energy $E_1$ or $E_2$ , then
>
> a. What will be the entropy $S(n)$ for such system? ($n$ is the number of particles with energy $E_2$). How can I derive the expression for $S(n)$?

This is how I solve:

$\Omega(E_2) = \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}$

Then,

S(n) = $k_B \ln \Omega(E_2) = k_B \ln \left( \frac{N!}{n! (N-n)! } \right)$

Is it the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Please note that [check-my-work questions are off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we assume $E_1$ (zero state) and $E_2$ (state 1), from this question, the system has n units of energy and N particles. The multiplicity is then $$\Omega (N,n) = \frac {(n+N-1)!}{n!(N-1)!}$$

and entropy can be calculated, $$S=k \ln \Omega(N,n)$$